# Czech diacritic on HTML

Tags: html, web, character-encoding

I'm trying to make some text in czech, but I can't success :-/

Web is http://esn.zcu.cz/world/

formate of the file and in meta is iso-8859-2 which should allow czech chars

Comment: Why not to use Unicode encoding? This would solve all diacritic character issue.

Comment: Can you provide a small sample of HTML that re-creates this and maybe a screenshot? It looks fine to me, but maybe that is my lack of Czech language :) All I know is: "Svíčková" and "pivo"

Comment: with utf it works even worse...

Comment: for example KoÅ¾eÅ¡nÃ­kovÃ¡ should be Kožešníková

Comment: I see "Dominika Kožešníková" just fine... This could be an issue with your browser / operating system

Answer (score 2):

Your webpage has `<meta charset="charset=utf-8">` and yet it isn't in UTF-8. Firefox interpreted it as ISO-8859-1, which makes vowels like `éóí` look okay, but then `č` you typed is being displayed as `è`.

Solution? You can fix the `meta` tag, but seriously, it's 21st century, you really should use UTF-8 everywhere. Convert the page to UTF-8, remove `<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=iso-8859-2">` and you'll be fine.

---

Note: your HTTP server returns this: `text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1`